# Eror while invoking lambda function AWS using c#

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sharepoint-online

ERROR Details says: platform not support exception was thrown,

more details are given below:

i was trying to create SharePoint list using Client side Object Model (CSOM) inside the Lambda function for which "Microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll" and "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RunTime.dll" are referenced inside the project

can anybody help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda Functions support .NET Core as referenced here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-app.html

Unfortunately CSOM Library is available only in .NET Framework referenced here:
[Using SharePoint CSOM inside .Net Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186888/using-sharepoint-csom-inside-net-core-application)

Some people have been able to hack together a fix: http://rajujoseph.com/getting-net-core-and-sharepoint-csom-play-nice/  - I have tested these methods with AWS tools for Visual Studio and can confirm that for AWS Lambda it will not work.

We are out of luck until CSOM is support on the .Net Core